# gradle wrapper downloaded multiple times for different projects

Tags: gradle, migration, nexus, gradlew

I have got micro-services where each service is a separate project. In the gradle wrapper properties files, I have defined the same distribution URL:

```
distributionUrl=http://nexus-server.com/nexus/content/repositories/software/gradle/2.14.1/gradle-2.14.1-bin.zip
```

Our nexus is migrated to a different server therefore I had to update the gradle wrapper properties file to use the new server address. I have got 2 questions:

1. Is there a way that I could tell gradle not to download the
   distribution from scratch as (in principal) the distribution is the
   same, only server address is changed?
2. Even if gradle wrapper downloads the distribution from the new nexus
   server, why is it repeating the action for each micro-service
   project instead of reusing the one downloaded for the first project
   (after it was build)?